# Multiplicar dos variables que contienen rangos

Tags: excel, vba

Estoy tratando de multiplicar dos variables (sean `ContractsQty` y `LeaseQty`) para obtener el total de lineas que tienen que crearse.

Estoy tratando de utilizar algo parecido a esto:

```
'Calcular cantidad de lineas
Dim ContractsQty As Range
Set ContractsQty = vcr.Range("Q2:Q" & Cells(Rows.Count, 17).End(xlDown).Row)
Dim LeaseQty As Range
Set LeaseQty = Sheets("Pivot").Range("B2:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlDown).Row)
Dim TotalLines As Long
Dim TotalContracts As Long
TotalContracts = ContractsQty.Count
Dim TotalLease As Long
TotalLease = LeaseQty.Count
Dim TotalofLines As Integer
TotalofLines = TotalContracts * TotalLease
```

pero arroja el error

> ```
> "Run-time error '6':" Overflow
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Es por detalles en el código, los resalte con comentarios en su respectiva linea:

```
Dim ContractsQty As Range
    Set ContractsQty = vcr.Range("Q2:Q" & Cells(Rows.Count, 17).End(xlUp).row) 'Usar xlUp en lugar de xlDown
Dim LeaseQty As Range
    Set LeaseQty = Sheets("Pivot").Range("B2:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).row) 'Usar xlUp en lugar de xlDown
Dim TotalLines As Long
Dim TotalContracts As Long
    TotalContracts = ContractsQty.Rows.Count 'Cuenta total de filas
Dim TotalLease As Long
    TotalLease = LeaseQty.Rows.Count 'Cuenta total de filas
Dim TotalofLines As Integer
    TotalofLines = TotalContracts * TotalLease
```